# New loop vs widget

Tags: loop, widgets

So, I have a sidebar that I'm going to list all posts in, I could just use a widget.
But is it proper to use a new loop instead of a widget, or preferential?

Comment: Widgets and loop are not comparable, it's like saying should I use a picnic basket or a car.

Comment: I wish I could award a bounty to that comment @Wyck

Answer (score 2):

You should always use widgets when you need to add any kind of content to the sidebar. The reason is very practical - once the project is over the owner of the site will not need to contact you just because he wants to put a banner before your "loop", and even during development it easier to just move a widget then edit your code when needed.

Widget are also reusable in all the sidebars of the site, and if you pack them as a plugin, or in separate file, it is easy to reuse them in other projects.

Many advantages for just a little amount of extra work.